# ViewController: create window

Tags: extjs, viewcontroller, extjs5

In ExtJS4 it was possible to do in a Controller:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['App.view.SampleWindow'],
    refs: [{
            ref: 'sampleWindow',
            xtype: 'samplewindow',
            autoCreate: true
    }],
    init: function(application) {
        var win = me.getSampleWindow();
        win.show();
    }
});
```

How can I accomplish this in a ViewController? The Viewcontroller has no refs property. And `lookupReference` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the window using [`Ext.widget()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-widget), like:

```
var win = Ext.widget('sampleWindow');
win.show()
```

Comment: would the window be scoped to the creating viewcontroller? so the viewcontroller can handle events from the window?

Comment: No. You can create a viewController for your `sampleWindow`.